# Opening Maps via intent the first time centers on user location, ignores geo:

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I've seen this example posted everywhere to open google maps centering on a specific point:

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", lat, lon);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

However it seems to me at least in the newest maps version the very first time this is called it ignores this and and instead zooms to the users location.  Is this a bug?

Comment: This also happens for me... Using Android 4.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize I never answered this question.  This is eventually what I used and it seems to work OK.  The above answer may as well!

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+lat+","+lon);
startActivity(intent);
```

To do the same thing except to start Maps in driving mode, do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+lat+","+lon);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by calling the intent twice via an AsyncTask. I have no idea if this is the correct way to do it but it worked for me!

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:0,0?q=%f,%f(%s)&z=40", lat, lon, square);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:0,0?q=%f,%f(%s)&z=40", lat, lon, square);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```